# Bash: tilde expansion within the word of parameter expansions

Tags: bash, shell

When I use the "Use Default Value" parameter expansion with a tilde (~) in Bash, it behaves differently depending on whether it's quoted. For instance:

```
echo ${unsetVar:-~}
# /home/foo
```

In this case, `${unsetVar:-~}` correctly expands to the `$HOME` when the variable unsetVar is unset. This shows that the tilde undergoes expansion as expected when it's not enclosed in quotes.

However, when I enclose the parameter expansion in double quotes:

```
echo "${unsetVar:-~}"
# ~
```

No tilde expansion. I suppose this is due to the https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html rule. Although I was aware of that rule beforehand, I thought it applies to only special characters *directly within* double quotes, like `"asdf ~ asdf"` but not to those *indirectly within*, as shown in the example.

I'm aware that `$HOME` can be substituted for `~`. However, I'm interested in finding out if there's a way to force the tilde expansion.

EDIT: ... to force the tilde expansion *within* one simple command
EDIT2: without introducing temporary variables

Comment: A way that _works_ is one thing, a way that's _documented to work_ and guaranteed not to be broken by a bugfix in the future is another. This is a fair question, but you're _really_ better off using `$HOME`.

Comment: `tmpVar=${unsetVar:-~}; echo "$tmpVar"` ?

Comment: @jhnc (I previously answered to jhnc that his answer does not count due to being not a simple command). I forgot to mention that the solution must be within one _simple command_.

Comment: @jhnc Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: `echo "$(tmpVar=${unsetVar:-~}; echo "$tmpVar")"` ?

Comment: @jhnc Clever. But again, I'm sorry for my amnesia. I meant "without introducing temporary variables".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know a trick

```
$ unset x
$ echo "${x:-${_/*/~}}"
/home/oguz
```

but you should just use `$HOME`.

Comment: Wow. How did you know that?

Comment: @Jinux It was revealed to me in a dream.

Comment: @jhnc Considering his and your solutions, I suppose providing another level of _expansion_ is an exception to the behavior of tilde expansions inside double-quotes. What do you think?

Comment: @Jinux you'd have to trace the flow of execution in each implementation to be sure what is happening. I can't immediately find the relevant part of the [source](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_bash)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be portable across all the POSIX shells I can get my hands on:

```
$ HOME="tilde expansion is protected    against splitting"
$ unset x
$ echo "${x:-$(printf '%s' ~/)}"
tilde expansion is protected    against splitting/
```

but you should just use `$HOME`.

Comment: This gives another insight. Thank you.

Comment: Try with `HOME=$'foo\n'`

Comment: @oguzismail ugly simple fix could be to `echo ~/`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/nPd5S0

Comment: @oguzismail okay, `printf '%s' ~/` :-P (the outer `echo` is from the question so I'm not too bothered by that)